# how to set user upload a pic and display the pic and add to cart that pic in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to set user's add pic and display pic and add to cart that pic.

profile.html

```
<li class="box nocursor" ng-repeat="item in items">
<img src="image location" width="100px" height="100px"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, your question is very blur. For uploading a pic, you can go through this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JeJenny/ZG9re/). For understanding it, refer [this blog](https://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs).

```
var uploadUrl = "/fileUpload";
```

use server call here to upload the file to server.And do some checks that the file is in required format.Once you have it on server, write controllers/services to handle *Add to cart* functionality.

Comment: @BalaDev: have u integrated server call ?